# laravel irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: php, laravel

this is my code which is send photo

```
Telegram::sendPhoto([
     'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
     'photo' => \Telegram\Bot\FileUpload\InputFile::create("http://dreamhouse.gocrm.uz/".$image->path)
      ]);
```

some times I get like this error.  "Bad Request: file "/var/lib/engine/data2/tmp/2020-11-06-15-01-34-16.jpeg" is too big for a photo [size:24MB]"

how I can chack image size, pls give advise.

Comment: you mean you want to know how to check the size of a file using PHP? How about the `filesize` function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: if whatever package you are uses stream then you can avoid this error